# Usage of disagree

Tags: verbs

> Everyone would disagree to help the criminals.

I wonder whether "disagree to help" is correct English.
I've looked up "disagree" in dictionaries, but I couldn't find "disagree" can be used with to-infinitive, like "agree".

Answer (score 1):

Although **disagree** normally functions as the opposite of  **agree**, **disagree** can't be used with a **to**- infinitive in the way you can use **agree**.

> "Everyone would **agree** to help."

is good English, but (surprisingly, I guess)

> "Everyone would **disagree** to help."

isn't correct.

A close equivalent in meaning might be:

> "Everyone would **decline** to help."

Comment: Should we regard "agree" as an intransitive verb when used with to-infinitive?

Comment: @SinK I think both "agree" and "disagree" are always intransitive verbs because we don't use either with a true direct object. We don't agree something or someone; we agree *to* something or *with* someone or something ... or, sometimes it's just simply, "We agree." "He agrees me [direct object]" is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are two slightly different meanings that are possible with "agree"

> I agree to help  (I "consent", or I will help)
>
> I agree with helping (I think helping is a good idea for other people too)

You could mean the opposite of the second meaning, in which case

> Everyone would disagree with helping criminals.

However it may be better to use "nobody"

> Nobody would agree with helping/to help criminals.

This lets you choose which sense of "agree" you want to use.